# how can I call a function in a directive from the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a function that sits in a directive and i want to be able to call it from the controller. how can i do that?

here is my directive:

```
angular.module('almApp')
      .directive('contactForm', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.sending = function () {
              $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
              $scope.status.message = "Sending your message...";
              $scope.status.styleClass = "info";
            }
          }
        };
      })
```

also my view element is as follows:

```
<div class="m-t-15 alert alert-{{status.styleClass}}" role="alert" contactForm>{{ status.message }}</div>
```

how can i call sending() from the controller?

Comment: You can just call it via scope itself, if controller is in the same scope as that of this directive and provided the method has been attached on the scope by the time you make the call from controller (directive link function runs later than controller instantation ).

Comment: @PSL - if i call `scope.sending` in the controller i get `scope is not defined`

Comment: Probably because you arent injecting scope. Also you have a typo in directive code as well scope and $scope that could fail too.

Comment: What about trying `$scope.sending()` in the controller, not `scope`

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you describe `sending()` function is the candidate to be defined in controller. You CAN call controller functions from directive if required, but it is non-sense to call functions defined inside nested directives. Nested scope shouldn't be visible to outer scope since you can have multiple instances of this directives inside one controller and each can actually define a different version of this function...